# SQL: How to get distinct value and it's count in separate column

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a MySQL table with a column called "level" like below.

```
| level
-----------
| High
| High
| Medium
| Low
| Low
| Medium
```

How would I go about counting the number of times each of these values occurs outputting a table like below from one query for a MS Chart (pie) control data source.

```
level  | count
---------------
High   | 1
Medium | 4
Low    | 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by the `level`. Aggregate functions like `count()` apply to each group

```
select level, count(*) as cnt
from your_table
group by level
```